# PHP Call function once and get the first result

Tags: php

For the php pro guys, what is the best practice for this scenario :

I have some function with two params `consult($id, $value)`, this function save that `id` and `value` in some database then returns me some codes :

`C1` = value has well been saved,

`C2` = there is already an entry with this value !

I call my function like this :

```
$id = "10";
$value = "ABCD";
$save = $block->consult($id, $value);
```

Then I get the result like this :

```
echo $save->{'return'}->result; // return C1 or C2
```

Now I think when I call `$save = $block->consult($id, $value);` It execute the function once, and when I `echo $save->{'return'}->result;` It execute it once again.

I thought about doing this to execute the function just once and print the result :

```
$block->consult($id, $value)->{'return'}->result;
```

With this it execute the function and return the result just one time, what do you think, is there a better idea ?

Comment: What does `$save` contain if you do a `print_r` ?

Comment: _“and when I `echo $save->{'return'}->result;` It execute it once again”_ - what makes you think that? There is no function call in that statement.

Comment: @executable it returns ` stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [result] => C2
        )

)`

Comment: You can retreive the result from `$save`. `$result = $save->return->result;`

Answer (score 1):

> when I echo $save->{'return'}->result; It execute it once again.

It will not execute consult function i.e $save = $block->consult($id, $value);

Please return function result in array or json format and Print_r result. It will give result of first execution call. if you call second time then it will give another id. Until and unless it will not execute two times. Your are accessing return result variable values.

Answer (score 0):

```
function consult($id, $value){

// your functionality 
 $res  = ''; // Store the return response and return it.
 return $res;
}
```

In your calling should be

```
$id = "10";
$value = "ABCD";
$result = $block->consult($id, $value);
echo $result;
```